# URL Scheme to open specific View with data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url-scheme

I've been looking around and could not find anything I was wondering if anyone could point me to a tutorial or help me out with the following:

I am making an app and want to be able to share on Twitter and when the twitter user clicks on the link (myapp://u/userId or myapp://s/objectId) it opens and specific View Controller ("/u/" for user and "/s/" for items)

I don't know if its possible or my "logic" is not correct, I am thinking that when the url is /u/ it opens the user view and then I can use the userId after the /u/ to PFQuery for the user, and same logic with the items and /s/...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!