# I'm trying to open a specific view controller when a user goes to a specific URL scheme

Tags: objective-c

I'm programming in Objective-C and I know that I need to implement this function in my AppDelegate

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
```

I can't find any good sources for doing something like this, does anyone know how I'd be able to?

I found this, but the question was unanswered.
[URL Scheme to open specific View with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884909/url-scheme-to-open-specific-view-with-data)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the scheme type and decide based on it.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[PaymentResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = nil;

   if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"app1scheme"])
    {
        viewController = [[Scheme1ViewController alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"app2scheme"])
    {
        viewController = [[Scheme1ViewController alloc] init];
    }
     else if (etc..)
    {
        etc...
    }

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, on top of this, do you know how I would attach a specific identifier onto the app scheme and depending on that, get the information needed?

Comment: The scheme is the identifier itself. Each scheme has a name, so you check for that name.